# How to resolve "cannot move out of borrowed content" due to filtering read_dir output?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to use `read_dir` to read the contents of a directory and then filter for just the files:

```
let xs = std::fs::read_dir(".")?
    .filter(|r_entry| {
        r_entry.and_then(|entry| {
            let m = entry.metadata()?;
            Ok(m.is_file())
        })
        .unwrap_or(false)
    })
    .collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>();
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c74b90188a1d04ce5646dcf8587da383))

The error message is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:6:13
  |
6 |             r_entry
  |             ^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I've tried various combinations of `&` and `*` around `r_entry` to no avail. What is happening?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b666c7bb80b88fbc5640a8c58ccb9e7e pick your favorite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate in `filter` only allows you to borrow `r_entry`. When you call `and_then`, this attempts a move. Instead, you can use the reference in a `match` like this:

```
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let xs = std::fs::read_dir(".")?
        .filter(|r_entry| match r_entry {
            Ok(entry) => entry.metadata().map(|m| m.is_file()).unwrap_or(false),
            Err(_) => false,
        })
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>();

    println!("{:?}", xs);
    Ok(())
}
```